# A Java FileOutputStream that keeps the File?

Tags: java, io

As far as I understand, Java's `java.io.FileOutputStream` doesn't keep the File object anywhere inside it. I have a use case where I want to get information about the file where I am writing to, and I want this in a method that receives an `OutputStream` (so, the idea is to downcast after a test based on `instanceof`).

Obviously I could write an adaptor, but I wonder if there is such a thing available on well-known libraries (cannot find it non Apache Commons or Guava).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just instantiate the `FileOutputStream` using the constructor that takes a `File` as the argument? Then you'd have the file handle.

Comment: The resulting FileOutputStream has a FileDescriptor handle, but this doesn't contain any information about the original file path.

Answer (score 0):

There are no public methods that return the `File` object from the stream. If you want to know where are you writing to - just send `File` object to your constructor and then open it with `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: I can't. I need to subclass a method that receives an OutputStream and is called from the outside. That the File is not saved in FileOutputStream is clear enough, what I'm asking is if there is a well known implemented subclass of FileOutputStream that actually does this.

Comment: Do you have control of the code creating the output stream?

Comment: No and it doesn't matter, cause I want to pass the file to the receiver, via the parameter of type OutputStream.